# Much of perf Output Not Supported

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, perf

I have only a limited set of supported stats for `perf` on my machine:

```
charles@charlesSpark-VirtualBox:~$ uname -r
4.4.0-36-generic
charles@charlesSpark-VirtualBox:~$ perf --version
perf version 4.4.16
charles@charlesSpark-VirtualBox:~$ ls /sys/devices
breakpoint  LNXSYSTM:00  msr  pci0000:00  platform  pnp0  power  software  system  tracepoint  virtual

$ perf list

 List of pre-defined events (to be used in -e):

 alignment-faults                                   [Software event]
 bpf-output                                         [Software event]
 context-switches OR cs                             [Software event]
 cpu-clock                                          [Software event]
 cpu-migrations OR migrations                       [Software event]
 dummy                                              [Software event]
 emulation-faults                                   [Software event]
 major-faults                                       [Software event]
 minor-faults                                       [Software event]
 page-faults OR faults                              [Software event]
 task-clock                                         [Software event]

 msr/smi/                                           [Kernel PMU event]
 msr/tsc/                                           [Kernel PMU event]
 power/energy-cores/                                [Kernel PMU event]
 power/energy-gpu/                                  [Kernel PMU event]
 power/energy-pkg/                                  [Kernel PMU event]
 power/energy-ram/                                  [Kernel PMU event]

 rNNN                                               [Raw hardware event    descriptor]
 cpu/t1=v1[,t2=v2,t3 ...]/modifier                  [Raw hardware event descriptor]
  (see 'man perf-list' on how to encode it)

 mem:<addr>[/len][:access]                          [Hardware breakpoint]
```

So as a result I cannot even get a cycle count:

```
charles@charlesSpark-VirtualBox:~$ perf stat -e cycles pwd
/home/charles

 Performance counter stats for 'pwd':

   <not supported>      cycles                   

       0.027393147 seconds time elapsed
```

Before looking in http://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/tools/perf/ I thought I'd ask. I have installed the pacakges `linux-tools-common` `linux-tools-generic` and a few others.

Comment: this is probably because you are running in a VM and the hypervisor is not making them available to the guest OS.